# Backbone collection's models-object incorrect structure?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-model, backbone.js-collections

I believe that, somewhere along the way, my Backbone collections aren't storing their models correctly. I'm also using [backbone-pageable](https://github.com/wyuenho/backbone-pageable) to have paginated collections, and my backbone app is based on https://github.com/alessioalex/ClientManager and some backbone tutorials.

Basically, as I understand it, Backbone Collections should have a models attribute that is:

```
Object
  models: Array
    0: Object
      model
      model, etc
```

But mine seem to have the structure:

```
Object
  models: Array
    0: Object
      attributes: Object
        tasks: Array (from my server JSON response)
        total_match, etc (other variables for pagination)
```

So thus, in my templates I always have to use tasks[0].each rather than just tasks.each

This also means that, when adding models to the collection, they aren't added to the array of models in tasks, but instead Backbone created another array in models, such that it becomes:

```
Object
  models: Array
    0: Object
      attributes: Object
        tasks: Array (from my server JSON response)
        total_match, etc (other variables for pagination)
    1: Object
      (new model attributes)
```

This then means that my template code, searching for tasks[0] doesn't pick it up. It also means that for my collections, I can't use collection.get(id), it returns nothing - even when using correct IDs and with a specified IDAttribute for the model.

I'm a bit stumped.

Comment: Does your REST endpoint return an array ?

Comment: Hi guys, JSON response: {"tasks":[{"id":"88", ... "}],"total_pages":1,"total_match":10,"total_tasks":14}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your server is returning a `tasks` Array nested in the JSON response.  In order for Backbone to know how to properly parse the JSON, you need to override the `parse()` method and tell it to use the `tasks` array as the source for your models.

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});    
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: MyModel,
        parse: function(response) {
           //tell Backbone to turn each element in 'tasks' into an instance of MyModel
           return response.tasks;  
        }
});
```

Comment: This was it! Totally forgot to change the parse function, or, in backbone-pageable it's parseRecords: `parseRecords: function(resp) {
      return resp.tasks;
    }` Thanks! But is there a way to then access the other JSON attributes outside of the array that i've chosen to parse?

Comment: Managed to answer my own question. When passing my JSON to the template, I can just send the backbone-pageable state object along too: `tmpl = that.template({ projects: projects_json, state: projects.state });`